# How can I adjust typeahead to be sensitive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I took this code here at http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset which seems to work fine when searching for the cars, but how can I get it to be completely sensitive? For example, one of the cars in the array is Mercedes Benz, when I search "Benz" I'll get a result, but when I search for "enz" or "ercedes" for example I do not get any results.

Comment: anyone? i would really like some help on this

Comment: Please show the code you are using.